# BeautifulSoup: How to find all href links in a div with a class?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

On disboard.org/ I am trying to collect all href's within a div with a class of 'server-name'.
Source-Code:

```
def scrape():
    url = 'https://disboard.org/search?keyword=hacking'
    response = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    areas = soup.find_all('div', class_='server-name')
    for area in areas:
        print(area.get('href'))
```

The error message given when this function is called is 'none' instead of the links.
Example:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace by:

```py
area.find('a').attrs['href']
```

**Full code**

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrape():
    url = 'https://disboard.org/search?keyword=hacking'
    response = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    areas = soup.find_all('div', class_='server-name')
    for area in areas:
        print(area.find('a').attrs['href'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrape()
```

**Output**

```
/server/484696439063314482
/server/560847285874065408
/server/715563459739385886
/server/720783958966796309
/server/471545766134153237
/server/733350720690061383
/server/653642434948890626
/server/589905664277610521
/server/729633522565775381
/server/734257173890334832
/server/637702746954530865
/server/326839256758616068
/server/495986950478757891
```